# displaying category and subject posts

Tags: templates, page-template

I have single post pages, that displays the page subheading based on the category name or subject name. I am having issues display category titles as well as subject name. Essential what I am trying to achieve is if the post is not selected as subject them display the page heading as a category.

Below is a snippet of my code, I have working to display subject names, however, I am struggling to display category names, if posts do not have subject names.

```
<?php

$classes = array();

$terms =  get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'subject' ); 

$categories = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category');  

if(sizeof($terms) > 1 ) {
    $classes[] = "reset";
}
else
{
    foreach($terms as $term)
    { 
        $classes[] = $term->slug;
    }
}
 ?>
    <div class="columns small-12 ">
            <div class="single-title <?php echo implode($classes, ' '); 
               ?>">
                <h2>
                    <?php  if(count($subjects) == 0)
                    {
                        $categories =  get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category' );
                    }
                    ?>
                </h2>
                <hr/>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: And where do you want to display that category/subject? Should it be placed in that <h2>?

Comment: They are displayed on the H2 tag

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get you right, but if so, this will solve your problem:

```
<?php
    $classes = array();

    $subjects =  get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'subject' ); 
    $categories = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category');  

    if ( count($terms) > 1 ) {
        $classes[] = "reset";
    } else {
        foreach ($subjects as $term ) { 
            $classes[] = $term->slug;
        }
    }

    $title_terms = ( count($subjects) ) ? $subjects : $categories;
?>
<div class="columns small-12 ">
    <div class="single-title <?php echo implode($classes, ' '); ?>">
        <h2><?php
            if ( count($title_terms) > 0 ) {
                echo $title_terms[0]->name;
                /* Or change it to this, if you want to display all of terms
                foreach ($title_terms as $term) {
                    echo $term->name;
                }
                */
            }
        ?></h2>
        <hr/>
    </div>
</div>
```